# Get array elements across all documents in the collection that match a specific array element content

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have the following document structure in my MongoDB and I am trying to return  an array of objects containing all prices for itemID "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312" across all documents using the following query but unfortunately it is always returning an empty array. Can someone please advice what I might be doing wrong here? and how I can get such a result?

Note: I am using promised-mongo in a Node.js app to access my MongoDB

Query I tried:

```
{ transDetails: { $elemMatch: { itemID: "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312" } } }
```

DB sample:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a688e7ea52deb6d4a6b6663"),
    "transactionID" : "1",
    "transDetails" : [ 
        {
            "itemID" : "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312",
            "price" : "22"
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "5a59c95b081c6c612bd17058",
            "price" : "24"
        }
    ] }

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6aa99a52deb6d4a67714"),
    "transactionID" : "2",
    "transDetails" : [ 
        {
            "itemID" : "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312",
            "price" : "35"
        }, 
        {
            "itemID" : "5a59c95b081c6c612bd17058",
            "price" : "24"
        }
    ] }
```

Comment: It's just `{"transDetails.itemID": "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312" }`, but it will return you whole documents that have at least 1 matching item.  To get prices only you need to use aggregation.

Comment: @AlexBlex thanks for your support, it worked with your proposed approach yet I was wondering if you can please example of aggregating results to return only the  price field? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find with projection to have only matched items in the `transDetails`:

```
.find({"transDetails.itemID": "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312"}, {_id:0, "transDetails.$": 1})
```

Will return

```
{
    "transDetails" : [ 
        {
            "itemID" : "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312",
            "price" : "22"
        }
    ] 
},
{
    "transDetails" : [ 
        {
            "itemID" : "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312",
            "price" : "35"
        }
    ] 
},
....
```

Wish you re-shape the documents, you can use aggregation:

```
.aggregate([
    { $match: { "transDetails.itemID": "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312" } },
    { $project: {
        _id: 0,
        transDetails: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$transDetails",
               as: "item",
               cond: { $eq: [ "$$item.itemID", "5a59c587fa9b4a212b0a1312" ] }
            }
         }
    } },
    { $unwind: "$transDetails"},
    { $project: {price: "$transDetails.price"}}
])
```

Which will give you

```
{
    "price" : "22"
},
{
    "price" : "35"
},
...
```

Comment: Thanks a heap for your efforts and time. I tried the first query it returned all documents in the collection. Aggregation returns "MongoError: Each element of the 'pipeline' array must be an object" Can you please advice if I missed anything here? Thanks

Comment: hmmm, but each element in the pipeline **is** an object, isn't it?

Comment: if you are referring to transDetails yes this is an array of objects

Comment: Try to change `$unwind` stage to `{ $unwind: { path: "$transDetails" } }` to make it *more object*. Which version of the db?

Comment: for  the records, *pipeline* is the array that we pass as a parameter to `aggregate` function. In my snippet it is an array of 4 objects, aka stages.

Comment: just tried changing unwind to { $unwind: { path: "$transDetails" } } and still getting the same error

Comment: db version v3.4.1

Comment: @MKM, how do you call it in your app? The code snippets are for mongo shell. Sorry I didn't mention it beforehand. You should translate it to match interface of your library.